# DataLoader API can't connect to Oracle

Tags: oracle

Using this xml:

```
<beans>
<bean id="dbDataSource"
      class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource"
      destroy-method="close">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="jdbc.driver.OracleDriver"/>
```

I'm getting this error:

> 2017-08-18 13:58:40,959 FATAL [TRFUpsertProcess] controller.Controller
>   createDao  (Controller.java:186) - Error creating data access object
>   java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource
>   cannot be cast to
>   com.salesforce.dataloader.dao.database.DatabaseConfig
>           at com.salesforce.dataloader.dao.database.DatabaseConfig.getInstance(Dat
>   abaseConfig.java:48)

My JRE is:

> java version "1.8.0_121" Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build
>   1.8.0_121-b13) Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 25.121-b13, mixed mode, sharing)

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: Without further info regarding your `DatabaseConfig file` it's hard to know, however I'd guess that the error is because of misconfiguration between DatabaseConfig bean and DataSource bean. can you post both beans ?

Comment: Here are the beans: <beans>
<bean id="dbDataSource"
      class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource"
      destroy-method="close">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver"/>
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:oracle:thin:@friskies:1523:starlims2dev"/>
    <property name="username" value=""/>
    <property name="password" value=""/>
</bean>

Comment: <bean id="queryAllTests"
      class="com.salesforce.dataloader.dao.database.DatabaseConfig"
      singleton="true">
    <property name="sqlConfig" ref="queryAllTestsSql"/>
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dbDataSource"/>
</bean>

Comment: <bean id="queryAllTestsSql"
      class="com.salesforce.dataloader.dao.database.SqlConfig" singleton="true">
    <property name="sqlString">
        <value>
            SELECT user from dual
        </value>
    </property>
    <property name="columnNames">
        <list>
            <value>USER</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
</beans>

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for responding.  Here are the beans:

    
    
    
    


    
    


    
        
            SELECT 
               t.accessionid,'1','0'
            FROM xdx_v_all_tests t
            WHERE t.accessionid like 'SFDC%'
        
    
    
        
            ACCESSION\ ID
            QUANTITY
            PRICE